# Hbase service not starting: Failed construction RegionServer

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, kylin

I am trying to start hbase service using start-hbase.sh in my Centos machine due to which Kylin is not reflecting any project and cubes.

Here is my error log:

```
2023-09-11 17:34:59,457 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.ensureAvailability(Epoll.java:79)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.<clinit>(EpollEventLoop.java:52)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:134)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.newChild(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:35)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:104)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:91)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoopGroup.<init>(EpollEventLoopGroup.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.NettyEventLoopGroupConfig.<init>(NettyEventLoopGroupConfig.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.setupNetty(HRegionServer.java:725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:573)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:3073)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:3091)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/liborg_apache_hbase_thirdparty_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_647067778412659259757.so: /tmp/liborg_apache_hbase_thirdparty_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_6470                          67778412659259757.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:36)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:203)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:198)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:61)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/liborg_apache_hbase_thirdparty_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_647067778412659259757.so: /tmp/liborg_apache_hbase_thirdparty_netty_transport_native_epoll                          _x86_647067778412659259757.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```